# Retrieve email from People or Group Field

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have People or Group Field

Normally I retrieve value of fields as:

```
var fieldUsuario = ctx.CurrentItem.Notificar_x0020_a
```

But now I dont want text value, I debbug it and it have email in span as:

```
<span class="ms-entity-resolved" id="Notificar_x0020_a_084ffd45-b361-458e-b55f-c824ba8995ec_$ClientPeoplePicker_i:0#.f|membership|email@mydomain.com_ProcessedUser0_UserDisplay" title="User, SubName" style="max-width: 331px;">User, SubName</span>
```

As you can see it have: `email@mydomain.com` I want to retrieve this value. How can I achieve it? Regards

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", 'SP.ClientContext', function (){                        
            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();            
            var oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
            var list = oWeb.get_lists().getByTitle('PeopleFieldTest');                      
            var item = list.getItemById(1);
            clientContext.load(item);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) {
                var userEmail = item.get_item("Notificar").get_email();//replace Notificar with your person column                               
                alert(userEmail);

            }, function (sender, args) {
                alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
            });
        });        
    </script>
```

[image]